# How can I configure a "catchall account"?

Tags: exchange-2010

I have an Exchange Server 2010, only on one machine with a total of 5 mail boxes.

I want to create a catchall email account. Any email to non existing user should go there. I've searched the internet and most of the options I found depend on having a separate server.

How can I do this on **one** server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure this can be done. Use the [Exchange 2007 catchall agent](http://catchallagent.codeplex.com).

In order for this to work properly with Exchange 2010, you should download all of the agent files to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\TransportRoles\agents\catchall`

When installing the agent, issue this command instead of the one in the `readme.txt`

> `install-transportagent -Name "CatchAll Agent" -TransportAgentFactory:CatchAll.CatchAllFactory -AssemblyPath:"C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\TransportRoles\agents\catchall\CatchAllAgent.dll"`

Besides those little caveats, just follow the readme.

Here are my sources on this:

- http://catchallagent.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=218519
- http://catchallagent.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=62204

Comment: Also don't forget "enable-transportAgent -identity "CatchAll Agent" !